# Unpivot table and calculate field

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, calculated-columns, unpivot

I have a bad schema and need to unpivot some fields and also calculate a date.
Here's what I have:

```sql
DATE1       DATE7       H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7
2011-09-19  2011-09-25  3   5   2   7   8   0   0
2011-09-26  2011-10-02  8   6   4   2   1   0   0
2011-10-03  2011-10-09  7   9   5   3   6   0   0
```

H1 is the number of hours spent on Monday. 
H2 is for Tuesday, and so forth. 
H7 is Sunday.

Date1 contains the full date on Monday and Date7 is for Sunday. This is a problem, because I need one date and one amount of hour per row.

This is what I need:

```html
DATE        HOUR
2011-09-19  3
2011-09-20  5
2011-09-21  2
2011-09-22  7
2011-09-23  8
2011-09-24  0
2011-09-25  0
2011-09-26  8
2011-09-27  6
2011-09-28  4
2011-09-29  2
2011-09-30  1
....
```

With UNPIVOT, unpivoting H1 to H7 worked, but I couldn't figure out how to solve the DATE field.

Here's the SQLFiddle to this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e012/2/0

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little string extraction from the column names do the trick:

```
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, CAST(RIGHT([WeekDay],1) AS int) - 1, Date1) As [Date],
            [Hour]
FROM        MyTable
UNPIVOT     (
                [Hour] FOR [WeekDay] IN (H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7)
            ) upvt
```

Comment: What if column names are A, B, C?

Comment: They ain't A B or C in the question. I don't make assumptions, I work with what's provided.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much Zoff!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that Date1 and Date2 represents intervals in one week, you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      dt DATE ,
      H1 INT ,
      H2 INT ,
      H3 INT ,
      H4 INT ,
      H5 INT ,
      H6 INT ,
      H7 INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '2011-09-19', 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 0, 0 ),
        ( '2011-09-26', 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0 ),
        ( '2011-10-03', 7, 9, 5, 3, 6, 0, 0 )

SELECT  DATEADD(dd, -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY Day ), dt) As Date,
        SomeValue ,
        Day
FROM    @t UNPIVOT( someValue FOR Day IN ( H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7 ) ) AS U;
```

Output:

```
Date        SomeValue   Day
2011-09-19  3           H1
2011-09-20  5           H2
2011-09-21  2           H3
2011-09-22  7           H4
2011-09-23  8           H5
2011-09-24  0           H6
2011-09-25  0           H7
2011-09-26  8           H1
2011-09-27  6           H2
2011-09-28  4           H3
2011-09-29  2           H4
2011-09-30  1           H5
2011-10-01  0           H6
2011-10-02  0           H7
2011-10-03  7           H1
2011-10-04  9           H2
2011-10-05  5           H3
2011-10-06  3           H4
2011-10-07  6           H5
2011-10-08  0           H6
2011-10-09  0           H7
```