# SQL Unpivot Rolling Date/Week Calculation

Tags: sql, pivot, azure-synapse, unpivot, cross-apply

This is my original table. It has a forecast release date and 6 columns representing the forecast for 6 weeks followed by the original week date.

| Forecast_Release_Date | Adj_Fcst_1 | Adj_Fcst_2 | Adj_Fcst_3 | Adj_Fcst_4 | Adj_Fcst_5 | Adj_Fcst_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-09-2023 | 299 | 312 | 309 | 248 | 282 | 270 |

Forecast Week 1 = 10-09-2023

Forecast Week 2 = 17-09-2023

Forecast Week 3 = 24-09-2023

Forecast Week 4 = 01-10-2023

Forecast Week 5 = 08-10-2023

Forecast Week 6 = 15-10-2023

I have successfully unpivoted the columns to rows.

| Forecast_Release_Date | Forecast_Release_Week | Adjusted_Forecast |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 299 |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 312 |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 309 |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 248 |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 282 |
| 03-09-2023 | 10-09-2023 | 270 |

This is my query:

```
SELECT Forecast_Release_Date
    ,DATEADD(Week, 1, Forecast_Release_Date) AS Forecast_Week
    ,Adjusted_Forecast
FROM (
    SELECT SourceFileInsertDateTime AS Forecast_Release_Date
        ,Adj_Fcst_1
        ,Adj_Fcst_2
        ,Adj_Fcst_3
        ,Adj_Fcst_4
        ,Adj_Fcst_5
        ,Adj_Fcst_6
    FROM MyTable
    ) p
UNPIVOT(Adjusted_Forecast FOR [Week] IN (
            Adj_Fcst_1
            ,Adj_Fcst_2
            ,Adj_Fcst_3
            ,Adj_Fcst_4
            ,Adj_Fcst_5
            ,Adj_Fcst_6
            )) AS unpvt
```

But I can't seem to get the rolling weekly dates for the **Forecast_Release_Week** column i.e., first row should be 10-09, second = 17-09, and so on.

> Note: This has to be dynamic based on the release date column and not
> hard-coded.

I tried following the code in [Unpivot table and calculate field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197289/unpivot-table-and-calculate-field) but it gave me the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P. S. - I am using Azure Synapse Data Warehouse SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 variants below for different dbms:

---

For SQL Server (as the question was originally tagged)

There is another way to "unpivot" in SQL Server using `cross apply` and `values`, this produces one row for each entry in the values, and you can output as many columns as you need. I like to layout the values as you see below as it almost mimics what the result will look like:

```
SELECT
       SourceFileInsertDateTime AS Forecast_Release_Date
     , CrossApplied.*
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
            (Adj_Fcst_1, dateadd(week,1,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
          , (Adj_Fcst_2, dateadd(week,2,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
          , (Adj_Fcst_3, dateadd(week,3,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
          , (Adj_Fcst_4, dateadd(week,4,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
          , (Adj_Fcst_5, dateadd(week,5,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
          , (Adj_Fcst_6, dateadd(week,6,SourceFileInsertDateTime))
        ) AS CrossApplied(Adjusted_Forecast, Forecast_Release_Week)
```

The technique is explained more fully [here](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/) also see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35621/29210)

---

For use in **Azure Synapse Data Warehouse SQL**

```
SELECT
    SourceFileInsertDateTime AS Forecast_Release_Date,
    Adjusted_Forecast,
    Forecast_Release_Week
FROM
    (
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_1 AS Adjusted_Forecast, dateadd(week,1,SourceFileInsertDateTime) AS Forecast_Release_Week FROM MyTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_2, dateadd(week,2,SourceFileInsertDateTime) FROM MyTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_3, dateadd(week,3,SourceFileInsertDateTime) FROM MyTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_4, dateadd(week,4,SourceFileInsertDateTime) FROM MyTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_5, dateadd(week,5,SourceFileInsertDateTime) FROM MyTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Adj_Fcst_6, dateadd(week,6,SourceFileInsertDateTime) FROM MyTable
    ) AS T
```

Comment: I have altered the answer to include calculated dates. It is untested and may need tweaking.

Comment: This looks good but i'd probably just leave the: 1, 2, 3, 4 in the Forecast_Release_Week column, and do the DATEADD(week, Forecast_Release_Week, SourceFileInsertDateTime) outside of the VALUES. Saves you from repeating the function calls

Comment: Requirement is to have the calculations dynamic. Presumably `SourceFileInsertDateTime` varies row to row and hence the other dates move as well.

Comment: Is there a way we can do this with unpivot instead of cross apply? I am using Azure Synapse Data Warehouse SQL. It prompts error near CROSS APPLY's '('.

Comment: Then why tag as "sql-server"? This also affects the way dates are calculated - it is **really important** to tell us the correct environment you are running the SQL in... it clearly also affects you because now it will take longer to get a solution.

Comment: I agree. I have updated the question to include the info/tag. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: do NOT include irrelevant tags (i.e. how is sql server relevant) this will only lead to confusion and unnecessary delays due to back & forth to establish which dbms applies. Please note this for future questions as well.